# No se ve lo mismo en el editor que en el hosting

Tags: html, css, hosting

Todo el HTML y el css se ve bien, pero el problema esta cuando lo subo al hosting (Hostinger), se descuadra todo y no se ve bien, os dejo aquí las imágenes.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

Comment: Sin código es dificil ayudarte, pero a simple vista es como si te faltara la carga correcta de los estilos. Revisa la consola para ver si hay errores de falta de archivos al navegar por el sitio web en el hosting. Para acceder a la consola pulsa el boton derecho sobre la web y selecciona "Insspeccionar" y vete a la pestaña consola.

Comment: Asegúrate que las rutas a los archivos que cargues sean relativas.

Comment: Con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador revisa en la consola si hay errores.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.